# Handling erros thrown by multer

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, middleware, multer

I have multer middleware to handle file uploads. My code looks like this.

```
const upload = require('./uploadMiddleware');
router.post('/support/case', setUserAuth, upload, async (req, res) => {
         try {
            validatePayload(req.body.payload);
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                error: 'Error in validating payload'
            });
        }
        dosomeProcessing(req.body.payload);
       return res.send(200);
})

function validatePayload(paylod) {
if(!payload.type || payload.type!=='XYZ'){
        throw new Error(`Invalid type ${payload.type}`);
}
}

uploadMiddleWare.js

const multer = require('multer'),
    { memoryStorage } = multer,
    path = require('path'),
    VALID_FILE_EXTENSIONS = ['.tar', '.zip', '.jpg', '.gif', '.png'];
const upload = multer({
    storage: memoryStorage({}),
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
        const fileExtension = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();

        if (VALID_FILE_EXTENSIONS.includes(fileExtension)) {
            return cb(null, true);
        }

        return cb(new Error(`Invalid file extension ${fileExtension} provided`));
    }
}).array('fileUploader', 3);

module.exports = upload;
```

As per my code logic if any error occurs in input I send 400 response code back. However now if any of the multer validation error occurs in this case if any invalid file extension is encountered or more than 3 files are uploaded then I get 500 error code. I believe its default express error handling. Is there a way to handle the errors gracefully and send 400 response code back in response?